# Is there a way to find the location of all variables that are or contain a certain type?

Tags: typescript

Imagine we have `type SomeObject = { ... }`. Data of that type is sometimes used directly (`console.log({ ...someObject })`) and sometimes nested inside other data structures (`console.log({ nested: { ...someObject } })`. I would like to statically analyze my codebase and find all variables that may hold data of that type.

I was hoping that the TypeChecker class from the compiler could provide this functionality, but I don't see anything available in its methods.

Comment: It's very unclear what your desired outcome is. Could you provide an example?

Comment: Edited my post to say this: "I would like to statically analyze my codebase and find all variables that may hold data of that type." Hopefully that's clearer!

Comment: I don't know of any tool that can help with this, and I imagine Typescript's model of types would interfere with the possibility... [all types are structural], meaning that it would be hard to identify all usages including the implicitly-typed ones.